# I'm copying and pasting my Python code over and over. How do I condense it into something more clean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading data from multiple DataFrames to create an object. One of the instance variables is a nested directory. The order of the DataFrame is known, but the column names in the Frame might be garbage. I'm currently mapping as follows:

```
iloc = 0
blocks[i].myvar['AA']['A']['a'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1
blocks[i].myvar['AA']['A']['b'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1
...
blocks[i].myvar['AA']['B']['a'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1
blocks[i].myvar['AA']['B']['b'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1
```

For 50 lines like this. Seems quite ugly, does anyone have a suggestion how to clean this up? I would just like to map columns 0:49 into an object that I can easily index into with the simple names ('AA', 'B', 'a') later on in my code.

-Raf

Comment: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: Aside from @Barmar's brilliant suggestion, it is possible for something more clever but you haven't provided enough information on the structure of your data/dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much info on your program but if you find yourself copying and pasting the same lines of code multiple times, you need to use a method also known as a function (since you're using python). A function allows you to run the same bit of code multiple times without having to copy and paste. Instead of...

blocks[i].myvar['AA']['A']['a'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1
blocks[i].myvar['AA']['A']['b'] = df_row.iloc[0, iloc]; iloc += 1 x n amount of times

..you can put it in a function and call the function's name in its place.

```
`def my_func(num):
   for x in range(num):
   //Insert code here

my_func(num)
```

Keep in mind that if you print the result in your function, you don't need to put print(my_func(num)). If you don't print the result, you will need to put the function call in a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop to workout repeated work and avoid copy and pasting the code if using a loop is possible